# Iterating through a JSON loop in JQuery and Ternary statements

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, object, iteration

Hey Guys I've been struggling with this for the last hour and pouring over
all the old thread on parsing out JSON but am running into two problems. The
first is being able to iterate over my two objects using this code.

```
 <script>
     $.each(data, function(index, obj) { 
        $.each(obj, function(key, val) { 
          items.push((key == "key") 
          ? '<input type="checkbox" name="' + val + ' /> ' 
          : '<div id="' + key + '">' + key + ': ' + val + '</div>'
        }); 
    });
 </script>
```

using `$.each(data[0 or 1], function(key, val)` will let me parse one or the other
section though.

The output from php so far is

```
[
    {
        "key":"4",
        "role":null,
        "region":"",
        "inspection_type":"melons",
        "inspection_number":"123",
        "customer_number":"",
        "report_date":"0000-00-00",
        "status":"0",
        "order_date":"2012-02-17 13:59:18",
        "customer":"",
        "customer_division":"",
        "location":"",
        "memo":null,
        "billing_key":null,
        "shipper":"",
        "po":"",
        "commodity":"",
        "label":""
    },

    {
        "key":"2",
        "role":null,
        "region":"Seattle",
        "inspection_type":"berries",
        "inspection_number":"1023",
        "customer_number":"206-420-9564",
        "report_date":"2012-10-21",
        "status":"1",
        "order_date":"2012-02-17 12:24:11",
        "customer":"Jd Daniel",
        "customer_division":"The Moon",
        "location":"West Seattle, WA",
        "memo":null,
        "billing_key":null,
        "shipper":"Shipper1",
        "po":"PO1",
        "commodity":"Commodity1",
        "label":"Label1"
    }
]
```

And will always be well formed.

The second issue is my ternary statement. Again using `$.each(data[0 or 1], function(key, val)` will at least pass me a TRUE when it hits `key =='key'` but will not pipe the out the expected `<input>` box but a True/False? I'm evidently doing MANY things wrong here, could someone point out my naivete for me?

**Edited**

Code refactored, ternary statement solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.push()` adds everything inside the parenthesis to a new index on the array:

```
items.push(key == "key") ? '<input type="checkbox" name="' + val + ' /> ' : '';
```

should be:

```
items.push((key == "key") ? '<input type="checkbox" name="' + val + ' /> ' : '');
```

Notice the return from the `if` statement is not enclosed in parenthesis. Since the only thing inside the parenthesis was `key == "key"`, you would only get either `true` or `false` added to the array.

Your `$.each()` code iterates through the array of objects returned from your PHP, but `key` is equal to the index of the array for the current iteration and `val` is the actual object in the index of the array. To access properties of the object in the `val` variable you can do this:

```
  $.each(data, function(index, obj) {
      items.push('<input type="checkbox" name="' + obj.key + ' />');
  });
```

Whenever I setup code to receive data from a web-service; I do a `console.log(data)` in the first line of the callback to see exactly how to access each property I want.

Comment: trying to use `obj.val` gives me an undefined and breaks everything?

Comment: In your code, `$.each(data, function(key, val) {`, the `key` variable is an index, starting at 0 and increasing by 1 each iteration. The `val` variable is an object with properties (the ones from your PHP output), so you can access those properties like this: `val.key` (I know that seems strange since your other variable is called `key` but this is getting the `key` property from the `val` object). You can get the `status` like this:  `val.status`. In my example I replaced your confusing variable names with `index` and `obj` since those variables are an index and an object (respectively).

Comment: I get it obj.name is the name of the key(s) inside my object, but in order to display ALL of the objects, there must be a better way then to name each one?

Comment: It looks like `$.each(data, function(index, obj) { $.each(obj, function(key, val) { items.push(key + val) }); });` was the answer by recursing deeper? But, is there a better way to do it?